# Laravel ZOHO SMTP Email failed to authenticate

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, zoho

I am using Zoho SMTP Configuration

```
DEFAULT_MAIL="gmail"
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=ses@imksa.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mina
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Test Sales
```

when I give space in MAIL_FROM_NAME as "Test Sales" without quotes website goes down
but mail is send successfully

I tried with quotes also

```
DEFAULT_MAIL="gmail"
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=ses@imksa.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mina
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Test Sales"
```

I get below error message

`Connection could not be established with host smtp.zoho.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.zoho.com:587 (Connection refused)`

In zoho mail configuration they have set FirstName=Test and LastName=Sales

Mails are not working only because of MAIL_FROM_NAME.

Can anybody suggest me solution

Comment: "Connection refused" is a pretty clear message, and is nothing to do with your configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems. Incorrect usage of SSL/STARTTLS and incorrect usage of mail addresses and names.

**Zoho supports both SSL and STARTTLS.**

You are specifying **ssl** but using the **starttls** port. The scheme **ssl** starts with encryption. This normally requires port 465. The scheme **tls** starts unencrypted and then switches to encryption via the **STARTTLS** command. This normally requires port 587.

[Email encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_encryption)

To use SSL:

```
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

To use STARTTLS:

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**Email address and name usage:**

Use **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=someone@example.com**.

You can combine **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS** with **MAIL_FROM_NAME**

```
"MAIL_FROM_NAME <MAIL_FROM_ADDRES>"
```

Replace the variable names with the values from your .env file:

```
$from = env('MAIL_FROM_NAME) . " <" . env(MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS) . ">";
```

Some class methods use this style:

```
->setFrom([env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), env('MAIL_FROM_NAME')])
```

Note: some email services do not allow you to change the **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS**. you must use the one registered for the account or a registered alias.

You can also specify the detail from address in **config/mail.php**:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

Comment: Yep, changed from SSL to TLS and worked for me